# 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th partial derivatives of real data obtained from FFTW are incorrect

Tags: c#

I calculated the 1st, 2nd and 3rd derivatives of sin(2.0*pi*j/lambda) (j varying from 0 to 255) by using fftw, fourier transforming it, multiplying by the appropriate and taking an inverse fourier transform. Plans used were out of place, with dummy input and output arrays. The real part of the resulting array is half of that of the analytical result though. I took care of aliasing while taking the derivatives by choosing the appropriate value of kx/ky. Just taking fftw and inverse fftw gave back the original array correctly.

The value returned by fftw was half that of the analytical values for all the derivatives.

If I do the same thing in the x direction (i instead of j), the values obtained are right only for the 1st derivative with respect to x, y derivatives are non-zero(the should be zero as variation is only in x) and the laplacian and biharmonic (4th derivative wrt x and y) are wrong.

In both cases, the imaginary parts of the derivatives are non-zero and large.

I tried a different plan using r2c and c2r instead, but that is giving the wrong values too.

Any suggestions will be helpful!

```
    void psiderivcalc(double *psi, double *dx, double *dy, double *del2, double *dxdel2, double *dydel2, double *del4)
```

{
    int i, j, ir, ir1, k;

```
fftw_complex *fdx, *fdy, *fdxdel2, *fdydel2, *fdel2, *fdel4, *out, *bt, *in;
fftw_plan p, q; 

out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) *N);
in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) *N);
bt = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) *N);
fdx = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
fdy = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
fdxdel2 = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) *N);
fdydel2 = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) *N);
fdel2 = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) *N);
fdel4 = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);

p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(lx, ly, in, bt, FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE);
q = fftw_plan_dft_2d(lx, ly, bt, out, FFTW_BACKWARD,FFTW_MEASURE);

for(i = 0; i < lx; i++)
{ 
    for(j = 0; j < ly; j++)
    { 
        ir = j*lx + i; 
        in[ir] = psi[ir] + 0.0*I; 
    }
} 

fftw_execute(p); 

double kx, ky, pref; 
int y1, x1, y2, x2; 
kx = 2.0*pi/lx; 
ky = 2.0*pi/ly;
for(i=0;i<lx;i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < ly; j++)
    {
        ir = j*lx + i;
        if(i<lx/2) 
        {
            x1 = i; 
            x2 = i;
        } 
        else if(i==lx/2.0)
        {
            x1 = 0; 
            x2 = i;
        } 
        else
        { 
            x1 = i - lx; 
            x2 = x1;
        }  
        if(j<ly/2) 
        {
            y1 = i; 
            y2 = i;
        } 
        else if(j==ly/2) 
        {
            y1 = 0; 
            y2 = j;
        } 
        else
        { 
            y1 = j - ly; 
            y2 = y1;
        }
        pref = -1.0*(pow((kx*x2),2.0) + pow((ky*y2),2.0));
        fdx[ir] = -1.0*kx*x1*I*bt[ir]; 
        fdy[ir] = -1.0*ky*y1*I*bt[ir]; 
        fdel2[ir] = pref*bt[ir]; 
        fdxdel2[ir] = -1.0*kx*I*x1*pref*bt[ir]; 
        fdydel2[ir] = -1.0*ky*I*y1*pref*bt[ir]; 
        fdel4[ir] = pref*pref*bt[ir];
    }
}

for(i = 0;i < lx; i++)
{ 
    for(j = 0;j < ly; j++)
    { 
        ir = j*lx + i; 
        bt[ir] = fdx[ir]; 
    }
}

fftw_execute(q); 

for(i = 0;i < lx; i++)
{ 
    for(j = 0;j < ly; j++)
    { 
        ir = j*lx + i; 
        dx[ir] = creal(out[ir]) / (double)N; 
    }
}
```

I found the other derivatives the same way as dx[ir](1st derivative wrt x) by changing bt[ir] each time before executing plan q, and out[ir] after execution. del2 is the laplacian, dxdel2 is derivative of the laplacian wrt x and del4 is the biharmonic.

psi[ir] was correctly initialised to a sine function in j before passing it on to the function.

```
    for(i = 0; i < lx; i++)
    { 
        for(j = 0; j < ly; j++)
        {
            ir = j*lx + i; 
            psi[ir] = sin(2.0*pi*j/lambda); 
        }
    }
```

This is an example of the output for del2(fftw), del2a(analytical), dx, dxa and ir(index). lambda = 8, lx = 16 and ly = 16, N = lx*ly, so sin function is periodic in this domain.

```
    0.308425    -0.616850   0.000000    0.000000    175
    -0.218090   -0.436179   0.000000    0.000000    191
    -0.000000   -0.000000   0.000000    0.000000    207
    0.218090    0.436179    0.000000    0.000000    223
    0.308425    0.616850    0.000000    0.000000    239
    0.218090    0.436179    0.000000    0.000000    255
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Computing the derivative requires to compute frequencies, which can be i/n or - (1-i/n) depending on what i is. Could you show us some code so we can see the actual problem and help you?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754033/integration-and-differentiation-of-fourier-series

Comment: @Hans Passant: the sine function I used satisfies the term by term differentiation theorem conditions, in this case, I checked the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is due to the following lines:

```
    if(j<ly/2) 
    {
        y1 = i; // should be j !!!
        y2 = i; // should be j !!!
    }
```

Also, watch the sign of the derivative:

```
    fdx[ir] = -1.0*kx*x1*I*bt[ir]; // should be a + !
    fdy[ir] = -1.0*ky*y1*I*bt[ir]; // should be a + !
```

Comment: Hello, I understood the 1st mistake, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I didn't understand the second one, forward fourier transforms are multiplied with a negative exponential term, exp(-k*n), right? So the derivatives should have a -1 as well.

Comment: I checked the ouput, did not have to do the second change for the code. First one was enough, thanks!

Comment: Please plot side by side `psi[j*lx+5]` and the derivative `psi[j*lx+5]`. The derivative must be positive if `psi` increases. In addition, prooving the link between the Fourier transform of a function and the Fourier transform of a function is acheived by performing an integration by part. There is a minus sign due to the integration of the exponential, and a minus sign due to the integration by part. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430858/fourier-transform-of-derivative

Comment: I checked, second change is correct too, thanks! I have another question, if I want to get derivatives of a non periodic array of numbers (i tried with an exponential function, and sine function with wavelength exceeding system dimensions), I get incorrect answers. What do you recommend I do? Zero padding, or using a filter are two things I have come across for this. Thanks

Comment: The problem with non-periodic functions is due to the artificial discontinuity introduced by the periodization. It triggers artificial frequencies: a phenomenon which is called spectral leakage. As the derivation is a high pass filter, these frequencies are inflated, thus making the error visible. To limit that problem, you can use a [window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) in real domain, which will mitigate the discontinuity. Presently,  you are using a rectangular window: try the Hann window, or a Tukey window.

Comment: In addition, the window in the real domain can be combined to a window in the frequency domain: a low pass filter. Such a filter will blur the image. As a result, the magnitude of medium frequencies are increased by the derivation, while high frequencies due to spectral leakage (or noise) are scaled down by the low pass filter. This technic is applied in filtered back projection algorithms for the reconstruction of computational tomographic images.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into what you said.